# How can I fix a UIcollectionViewCell from displaying an empty cell?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have purposely left an empty image in my assets catalog so that I can get my collectionView to somehow skip that image if it is nil, but so far it will render an empty image in that cell. It is better than crashing my app but how can I get it to skip that image?

here is my cellForItemAt indexPath code. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: K.collectionViewCell, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let image = RoomModel.roomModel.rooms[indexPath.item]
        if let image = image {
            cell.imageView.image = image
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Model Solution:

```
import UIKit

    var data = [long list of UIImage(named: ...)]

class RoomModel {
    var rooms = data.compactMap { ($0) }
    
    var roomNo = 0
  
    func setRoomNo(sender: Int) {
        roomNo = sender
    }
    
    func getRoom() -> UIImage {
        let image = rooms[roomNo]
        return image
    }
    
}
```

itemForRow Solution:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: K.collectionViewCell, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.imageView.image = self.roomModel.rooms[indexPath.item]
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: What does “skip that image” even mean? If your goal is to say `cell.imageView.image = nil` why not say it? If not, what’s the real goal here?

Comment: I'm trying to not render an empty cell, at the moment when the cell at indexPath gets to the empty image object it displays an empty cell. I would like it to recognise that the image at that indexPath contains nil and instead place the next image from the array in the cell.

Comment: Then you need to change the data model. By the time you are asked for a cell, it’s too late to omit it.  You don’t omit a cell; you omit the data. Less data, fewer cells. Do you see? It’s not the job of `itemForRow` to think, it’s the array’s job to change.

Comment: Oh thank you! That makes perfect sense and explains why all my attempts failed. I will write a function for getting the data in the model, and call that function in `itemForRow`

Comment: Not just in `itemForRow`. All methods need to see the data consistently. That is why you need the data itself to be what changes.

Comment: I'm not to sure how to do that but will persevere, my data consists of 200 images in the asset catalog, I then have an array of references to the images in my model. Something like a function that loops through my image references to check if `!= nil` to then populate another array with that outcome?

Comment: Just use compactMap to eliminate nil from array of Optionals... Or filter if the situation is more complex.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much ill get to it and try that.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to modify the data model to not include it if the image is nil and can be done by a simple if check before adding it in the model and then your cell would not render it as it is omitted from the data model.